# Nodejs chatServer Termination

Tags: node.js

My nodejs chatserver terminates at 1400 sockets. What can be the reasons for this. I am using forever to keep it running. I get this error message.

```
#
# Fatal error in ../deps/v8/src/heap/incremental-marking.cc, line 488
# CHECK(success) failed
#

==== C stack trace ===============================

 1: V8_Fatal
 2: ??
 3: v8::internal::IncrementalMarking::OldSpaceStep(long)
 4: v8::internal::FreeList::Allocate(int)
 5: v8::internal::PagedSpace::AllocateRaw(int)
 6: v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRaw(int, v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::AllocationSpace)
 7: v8::internal::Heap::AllocateStruct(v8::internal::InstanceType)
 8: v8::internal::Factory::NewStruct(v8::internal::InstanceType)
 9: v8::internal::Factory::NewCodeCache()
10: v8::internal::Map::UpdateCodeCache(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Map>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Name>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Code>)
11: v8::internal::IC::ComputeHandler(v8::internal::LookupIterator*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Name>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>)
12: v8::internal::LoadIC::UpdateCaches(v8::internal::LookupIterator*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Name>)
13: v8::internal::LoadIC::Load(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Name>)
14: v8::internal::LoadIC_Miss(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*)
15: ??
error: Forever detected script was killed by signal: SIGILL
```

> node version
>
> node -v
>
> v0.12.7
>
> npm -v
>
> 2.11.3

Memory usage

I think the server is leaking memory

root@chat-server:/home/prod# ps aux --sort -rss

USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND

root     29368  9.7 70.7 3673332 2864364 ?     Sl   Mar30 146:12 chatserver.js

Comment: Have you checked memory usage?

Comment: What node version are you using and can you post some of the relevant code?

Comment: error: Forever detected script was killed by signal: SIGILL
What does this mean??

Comment: @NodariLipartiya It is using 70% memory when I checked it and when it reaches the limit, it gets killed. Normally process memory usage is 8.7%.

Comment: @mscdex I have added npm and node versions

Comment: @SureshKoya when the process is killed manually or terminated due to out of memory, we get that error

Comment: try to use tools like heapdump to find memory leak. I once tried to do so, but didn't get anything useful. As I've read it is not easy to find memory leaks in node(